# BigQuery Google Analytics Automation Question

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Hello: Can someone please help me with this issue.

All our campaigns begin with a date

"20200312_NEWS_....."

I want to be able to get "New User" information for a 7 day period (i. 2020-03-12 to 2020-03-19)

How can I automate this process? I have 100's of these campaigns. I know my start date because its in the campaign name. I know my end date because its just +7.

I want to do dumb it down like: Start_Date = Left(trafficSource.campaign,8)  End_Date=Left(trafficSource.campaign,8) +7. But then how do i tell it to give me info of new users from Start_Date to End_Date. 
[enter image description here][1]

This is my very basic code:

SELECT
trafficSource.campaign AS Campaign,

-- New Users (metric)
  COUNT(DISTINCT(
      CASE
        WHEN totals.newVisits = 1 THEN fullVisitorId
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      )) AS New_Users

FROM
  `Table_1.ga_sessions_*`

WHERE totals.visits = 1 and   _table_suffix BETWEEN '20200101'
  AND '20201231'

GROUP BY
trafficSource.campaign

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correct, you are looking to extract date from the Campaign name and then trying to add 7 to it and getting all the new users

Here is something you can try

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(SUBSTR('20200312_NEWS_SampleData',0,8))), DATE_ADD (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(SUBSTR('20200312_NEWS_SampleData',0,8))), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I get my start date and end date. I am able to parse date. But for example if the campaign start date is "2020-01-03" and end date is "2020-01-10" But the "new user" data is from "2020-01-03" to "**2020-04-05**". The "new user" is not giving me data from date range " "2020-01-03" to "**2020-01-10**"

My Code:

SELECT
trafficSource.campaign AS Campaign,

Case When (SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,10,4)) = 'news' then PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,0,8))) end as Start_Date,
Case When (SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,10,4)) = 'news' then DATE_ADD (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',(SUBSTR(trafficSource.campaign,0,8))), INTERVAL 7 DAY) end as End_Date,

-- New Users (metric)
  COUNT(DISTINCT(
      CASE
        WHEN totals.newVisits = 1 THEN fullVisitorId
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      )) AS New_Users

FROM
  `ga_sessions_*`

WHERE totals.visits = 1 and   _table_suffix BETWEEN '20190101'
  AND '20201231'

GROUP BY
trafficSource.campaign

Order By 
2 Desc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw0HG.png)

Comment: Another annoying thing is 

when I change date range to: _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20201231'

it tell me "Failed to parse input string "2020xxxx"" How can I move past this. if cannot parse then skip

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured it out. But I wrote the worst code in the galaxy. Can someone help me make it more efficient:

Select Table_XYZ.Campaign, Table_XYZ.Start_Date, Table_XYZ.End_Date, SUM(col_1)
From 
(

Select
b. Campaign, Start_Date, End_Date ,

(Case When a.date>= b.Start_Date AND a.date<= b.End_Date then SUM(a.New_Users) End) as col_1

From  TABLE_1.VW_GA_TABLE1`a 
Left outer join TABLE_2.GA_TABLE2` b

ON a.Camp = b.Campaign

Group by 
b.Campaign,
a.date, b.Start_Date,b.End_Date

Order By b.Campaign Desc) Table_XYZ

Group By Table_XYZ.Campaign, Table_XYZ.Start_Date, Table_XYZ.End_Date